# Accessibility using custom textview for Font Icons

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

I created a custom TextView to use my font icons. My issue is that I need accessibility but I need set the accessibility description ignoring the font unicode.

```
class FontIcon(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {

    init {
        val typedArray: TypedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontIcon, 0, 0)
        val fontOrdinal: Int = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.FontIcon_iconStyle, 0)

        FontHelper().setTextView(this, fontOrdinal)

        super.setText(Html.fromHtml(this.text.toString()))

        typedArray.recycle()
    }
}


class FontHelper {

    fun setTextView(text: TextView, fontOrdinal: Int): TextView {
        val selectedFont =  R.font.icon_line

        val context = text.context.applicationContext
        val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, selectedFont)
        text.typeface = typeface
        text.importantForAccessibility = IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO <- I added this to ignore for now the reading of the unicode
        return text
    }
}
```

in the XML is like this:

```
    <br.com.mypackage.FontIcon
        android:id="@+id/icon_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="\ue81a"
        android:textColor="@color/heavy_grey"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lab_tube_experiment"/>
```

How can I set the accessibility description in this custom TextView ignoring the text that is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set `contentDescription` on a `TextView` and it will announce that instead of the contents.